# How make Spring Cloud Config Monitor wait until zookeeperis running?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-config

Currently if I startup a service with the dependencies (below), and Zookeeper is not running, it will fail.

I want to change this to do two things:

1. Startup the service but wait until zookeeper is available
2. Allow specifying a specific kafka to use instead if it spinning up its own

I get the error:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while building outbound endpoint
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at com.mycompany.main(Launcher.java:20) [classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while building outbound endpoint
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:125) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:152) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:124) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.bindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:238) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1232) ~[zkclient-0.9.jar:na]
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:156) ~[zkclient-0.9.jar:na]
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:130) ~[zkclient-0.9.jar:na]
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:76) ~[kafka_2.11-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:58) ~[kafka_2.11-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.apply(ZkUtils.scala) ~[kafka_2.11-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicAndPartitions(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:171) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicsIfAutoCreateEnabledAndAdminUtilsPresent(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:153) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:108) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:60) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:110) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that waiting for a running zookeeper is possible, but the following can be a viable workaround.

Try to set the `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoCreateTopics` to `false` (ref: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/37) to bypass zookeeper or set the `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkConnectionTimeout` (default is 10000) to a higher value.

To set specific brokers use the `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers` and the `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.defaultBrokerPort` settings.

[Spring Cloud Apache Kafka Binder docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR2/#_apache_kafka_binder)